# queryset django relationship

Tags: python, django, model, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Income(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField('Date', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, help_text="User Income")

class Invoice(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key=True)
    income = models.ForeignKey(Income, null=True, blank=True, related_name='Income')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='User_Invoice')
```

and I need to get the "Income" that are not associated with any "Invoice". I find no way to see this problem. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Dont use spaces in `related_name`.

Comment: @karthikr OK, anyway is an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter using `__isnull`:

Normally, Django automatically follows relationship fields using the lowercased name of the related model:

```
Income.objects.filter(invoice__isnull=True)
```

Here, you've specified the `related_name` attribute, so you need to use that:

```
Income.objects.filter(Income__isnull=True)
```

Note that this reveals that your related name attribute for the `income` FK on `Invoice` is backwards.  I see no reason for you to be setting a `related_name` at all, but if you do need one it should describe how the invoices are related to incomes, not vice versa.

Comment: fieldset "bill" does not exist in the model "income". can equally?

Comment: @funktasmas Is that the error message you get ? There is no reference to bill in what you have shown.

Comment: Where did 'bill' get into it?  You can filter on a reverse foreign key relationship, using the lowercased name of the related model.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Yes, this will work.  As the docs describe: "It works backwards, too. To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model."

Comment: @karthikr unfortunately I could not find a way to solve this problem

Comment: Did you actually try it out ?

Comment: @karthikr unfortunately yes

Comment: See the edit - related names matter.  Which makes sense now that I think about it, since they're how you handle multiple FKs to the same model and the reverse relationship has to be able to disambiguate.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I can say that with the changes you made, if the code works really;) I thanks your help.